# Zsh/Bash: Path isn't what it should be

Tags: python, bash, dropbox, zsh

I stumbled upon something I just can't figure out. Following situation: I downloaded the python frontend to control dropbox via command line (dropbox.py). I put this file in the folder:

```
/home/username1/.dropbox-dist/dropbox.py
```

I made a simple bash script in /usr/bin called "dropbox":

```
#!/bin/bash

python /home/username1/.dropbox-dist/dropbox.py
```

Now when i run it following happens:

The whereis for the file:

```
root@linux_remote /home/username1 # whereis dropbox
dropbox: /usr/bin/dropbox
```

When i run it:

```
root@linux_remote /home/username1 # dropbox
zsh: no such file or directory: /home/username2/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Yeah. It tells me another username. To be specific: I'm logged in via SSH on this linuxbox. On the remote shell there is byobu running. In byobu runs zsh. Username2 equals the user that I'm currently logged in with on my local linuxbox, with which I connected:

```
username2@linux_local /home/username2 # ssh username1@linux_remote
```

Thats how I am connected.

So there must be a variable which was passed to my remote shell from my local shell, and python seems to read it, but I can't figure out which it would be.

Now.. look at that: When I type in the command that I wrote into the bash script:

```
username2@linux_remote /home/username2 # python /home/username1/.dropbox-dist/dropbox.py
Dropbox command-line interface
```

So it runs if I do it manually. 
Another thing: If I run it with the whole path it works too:

```
root@linux_remote /home/username1 # /usr/bin/dropbox
Dropbox command-line interface
```

And it does work if I run it via login-shell, for example using "bash -l" and then trying to run "dropbox".

It doesn't work either if I change the hashbang to "#!/usr/bin/zsh"

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`whereis` doesn't do what you think: it searches a specific set of directories, not `$PATH`. `which` searches `$PATH` so you need to use `which` to find out which executable will be executed by a given name.

Edit: `which` as an external program (for shells that do not have a builtin command, such as `bash`) will not give a right answer for some cases, e.g. shell aliases. The `type` builtin should be used instead (it also should be available more widely as it's mandated by POSIX, though not necessarily as a builtin).

Comment: Ah! Thank you! Now I see what has happened. There is an alias set in my zsh-conf:

which dropbox
dropbox: aliased to /home/username2/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd

Comment: In my **bash** installation, `which` is an external command (`/usr/bin/which`) while `type` is the built-in that does what @user2190489 needed. (I don't know if `which` is builtin to **zsh** or not.)

Comment: @Robᵩ `which` is a builtin in zsh but why does it matter?

Comment: Because only a builtin can detect an aliased command. Had the OP been using bash, `type` would have found his problem; `which` would not have. (I don't see in the original question that he specified which of bash or zsh he was using.) Regardless, +1 for an excellent answer.